# Conditional errors after upgrading to EE 2.9 (just a helpful hand)

Tags: ee2, ee2-upgrades

The upgrade we did last night from 2.8.1. to 2.9 seemed OK. However we only tested the back-end so far!

While running the front-end we're getting these errors messages on all pages…

> Error
>
> You have an invalid conditional in your template. Please review your conditionals for an unclosed string, invalid operators, a missing }, or a missing {/if}.
>
> Lexer State: if: is a reserved prefix.

Of course we're focussed on finding incorrect conditional errors and couldn't find any! Checked 50+ templates. Close to giving up we found the issues caused by a missing } in a script in our HTML footer…..

Comment: Yes the syntax seems more strictly enforced...I've found a number of missing } and / in my code, even an entirely missing {/if}.  I just remove big chunks from my template to quickly narrow it down to smaller areas...it's usually not hard from there.

Comment: Please, move the answer to a proper answer and mark it as right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the syntax seems more strictly enforced...I've found a number of missing } and / in my code, even an entirely missing {/if}. I just remove big chunks from my template to quickly narrow it down to smaller areas...it's usually not hard from there.

(move to answer as per Robson)

Comment: i use indentation in template files and a customised ExpressionEngine syntax highlighter (Sublime Text editor) That helps a lot for reviewing code (incorrect tags not coloured)

Answer (score 0):

I also found this case:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="resources" status="open" url_title="{last_segment}" limit="1" disable="member_data|trackbacks|pagination" track_views="one"}
{exp:ifelse parse="inward"}
     {if xxx}


     {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:ifelse}
```

did not work, but

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="resources" status="open" url_title="{last_segment}" limit="1" disable="member_data|trackbacks|pagination" track_views="one"}
{exp:ifelse parse="inward"}

     {if xxx}

     {/if} 

{/exp:ifelse}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

did.  Note the order of the channel entries tag and the closing IfElse tag in relation to the opening tags.